# Loopback/Strongloop failed with ssh2 function callback Error: write ECONNABORTED

Tags: javascript, loopbackjs, strongloop, cisco, libssh2

I want to have a REST API that would return in web browser some cisco router CLI output from Cisco CLI command inputs via REST request using ssh2 and loopback.

I can't figure it out because of these errors.

The code below will run a few milliseconds returning some correct and expected output but then breaks the loopback instance at server side will break/stop.

Error encountered:

```
C:\LOCAL_APPS\Loopback\filedir\node_modules\async\dist\async.js:955
       if (fn === null) throw new Error("Callback was already called.");
                     ^

Error: Callback was already called.
at C:\LOCAL_APPS\Loopback\filedir\node_modules\async\dist\async.js:955:32
at C:\LOCAL_APPS\Loopback\filedir\node_modules\async\dist\async.js:3871:13
at interceptInvocationErrors 
(C:\LOCAL_APPS\Loopback\filedir\node_modules\strong-remoting\lib\remote-
objects.js:713:22)
at C:\LOCAL_APPS\Loopback\filedir\node_modules\loopback-phase\node_modules\async\lib\async.js:154:25
at C:\LOCAL_APPS\Loopback\filedir\node_modules\loopback-phase\node_modules\async\lib\async.js:154:25
at C:\LOCAL_APPS\Loopback\filedir\node_modules\loopback-phase\node_modules\async\lib\async.js:154:25
at C:\LOCAL_APPS\Loopback\filedir\node_modules\strong-remoting\lib\remote-objects.js:679:7
at C:\LOCAL_APPS\Loopback\filedir\node_modules\strong-remoting\lib\http-context.js:305:7
at callback (C:\LOCAL_APPS\Loopback\filedir\node_modules\strong-remoting\lib\shared-method.js:
```

---

```
Stream :: close :: code: 0, signal: undefined
events.js:183
  throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
  ^

Error: write ECONNABORTED
at _errnoException (util.js:1024:11)
at Socket._writeGeneric (net.js:767:25)
at Socket._write (net.js:786:8)
at doWrite (_stream_writable.js:387:12)
at writeOrBuffer (_stream_writable.js:373:5)
at Socket.Writable.write (_stream_writable.js:290:11)
at Socket.write (net.js:704:40)
at SSH2Stream.ondata (_stream_readable.js:639:20)
```

---

Under  common/models/device.js:

```
'use strict';

module.exports = function(Device) {

Device.getIPInterfaceBrief = function(ipaddr,cb){
var filter = {
    include:{
    relation: 'infosheet',
        scope:{
            fields:['data']
        }
    }
}
var Client = require('ssh2').Client;
var conn = new Client();
conn.on('ready', function() {
console.log('Client :: ready');
conn.exec('show ip int br', function(err, stream) {
  if (err) throw err;
  stream.on('close', function(code, signal) {
    console.log('Stream :: close :: code: ' + code + ', signal: ' + signal);
    conn.end();
  }).on('data', function(data) {
    cb(null,"data: " + 'done')  //or cb(null,"data: " + data)
    console.log('STDOUT: ' + data);
  }).stderr.on('data', function(data) {
    console.log('STDERR: ' + data);
  });
});
}).connect({
  host: ipaddr,
  port: 22,
  username: 'routerusername',
  password: 'passwordhere'
});
console.log("check 1");
};

Device.remoteMethod('getIPInterfaceBrief',{
 description: "Returns the brief interface information of a device",
   accepts:{
   arg:'ipaddr',
   type: 'string',
   required: false
 },
 http:{
   path:'/:ipaddr/getIPInterfaceBrief',
   verb: 'get'
 },
 returns:{
   arg:'interfaceinfo',
   type:'any'
 }
 });
}; //module.exports
```

REST TEST URL:

`http:// localhost:3000/api/adevices/some-ip-here/getIPInterfaceBrief`

Error encountered after few seconds API responded the get REST request:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I temporarily added some try catch statement it worked somehow.

I think loopback is not part of the issue.

Hope you have better fix since the code works on other machines like Linux system but for Cisco routers have some problem with the line "conn.end".

Added try and catch to capture the errors..

```
if (err) throw err;
stream.on('close', function(code, signal) {
  console.log('Stream :: close :: code: ' + code + ', signal: ' + signal);
  try {
    conn.end();
  }catch (err){
      console.log("error occured",err);
  }
}).on('data', function(data) {
  console.log('STDOUT: ' + data);
}).stderr.on('data', function(data) {
  console.log('STDERR: ' + data);
});
```

[My test did capture the error see here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5GFHa.png)